# best practice for catching all exceptions and consolidating them

Tags: c#, .net, exception, inner-exception

I want to consolidate all exceptions.
Is this a good practice to do so?

```
 string consolidatingAllException = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                // some process();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                while (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    consolidatingAllException += (ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
            }
```

Comment: This isn't even your question but you need to do `while (ex != null) { exceptionString += ex.Message; ex = ex.InnerException; }`; your code as posted is just an infinite loop if there's at least one inner exception.

Comment: Why not a `List<Exception>`?

Comment: What are your requirements? Did you have a look at the [Enterprise Library Exception Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203116.aspx) block?

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to log all your exceptions together for historic reasons or reviewing them later I suggest using [Trace Listener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t(v=vs.110).aspx)
Just trace the exceptions in catch and log them using Trace.TraceInformation() and eventually flush them into a log file